# Python histogram stacked with categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Lets say I have a pandas Dataframe of cars prices and some features in other columns including heated seats. I'm struggling to plot the price of the cars in relation to if the car has heated seats (1==True,0==False). I've started with this so far which doesn't work properly.

```
cars[['Price','Heated Seats']].plot.hist(stacked=True)
```

I've been looking for a while and couldn't find a simple solution as well as a way to hist plot side by side bars.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and if you can expected output. Following this guide maybe useful https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: are you trying to plot a pair of heated/non-heated bars for each price segment?

Comment: The price would be on the x-axis and a count of the amount of cars for the y-axis. There are varying price points and the goal would be to see the count of cars with heated seats on top of the count of the different cars price points.